# What are the absolutely bare minimum requirements for running local juju?

Tags: juju, lxc

I have read the documentation on running local juju with lxc. However, the dependencies in the docs seem kind of extensive for that, eg. why would it need libvirt (except for maybe the bridge nic ), what about zookeeper?

What is really minimaly needed to run juju with lxc?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need libvirt anymore (using juju from the PPA), I've corrected the documentation to reflect that but you do need zookeeper and the resulting java stuff.

We don't really have an "absolute minimum" that we track, however an Amazon [t1.micro](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) is probably the smallest thing we test on:

> - 613 MB memory
> - Up to 2 EC2 Compute Units (for short periodic bursts)
> - EBS storage only 32-bit or 64-bit platform
> - I/O Performance: Low

According to Amazon [one EC2 compute unit](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_an_EC2_Compute_Unit_and_why_did_you_introduce_it) is:

> One EC2 Compute Unit provides the equivalent CPU capacity of a
>   1.0-1.2 GHz 2007 Opteron or 2007 Xeon processor. This is also the equivalent to an early-2006 1.7 GHz Xeon processor referenced in our
>   original documentation.